# TYPO3: Render a plugin via Typoscript or ViewHelper and change settings

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, view-helpers

I would like to load a plugin dynamically according to some data. First I tried to do it with Typoscript, but after some research I figured out, that it is not possible to change the settings of the plugin ([see old forum entry](http://typo3.3.n7.nabble.com/cObject-data-an-ein-plugin-senden-td246595.html)).

I need to change `settings.simplepoll.uid` according to the passed data:

This is the Typoscript I tried:

```
lib.loadSimplepoll = USER
lib.loadSimplepoll {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = Simplepoll
    pluginName = Polllisting
    vendorName = Pixelink

    switchableControllerActions {
      SimplePoll {
        1 = list
      }
    }

    settings < plugin.tx_simplepoll.settings

    settings {
        simplepoll {
            uid.current = 1
        }
    }
}
```

The call in the template looks like that:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.loadSimplepoll">{newsItem.simplepoll}</f:cObject>
```

After figuring out, that changing the settings is not possible, I tried a viewhelper:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\ViewHelpers;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;  

class LoadSimplepollViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper
{
    /**
     * @param int $uid Uid of poll
     * @return string
     */
    public function render($uid) {
        $cObj = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer');

        $configurationManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Configuration\\ConfigurationManager');

        $simplepollTs = $configurationManager->getConfiguration(
            \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_SETTINGS,
            'simplepoll',
            'Polllisting'
        );

        $ttContentConfig = array(
            'tables'       => 'tt_content',
            'source'       => 1030,
            'dontCheckPid' => 1
        );

        // returning this works perfectly!
        // but I need to change the "settings.simplepoll.uid"
        $data = $cObj->RECORDS($ttContentConfig);

        $cObj->start($data, 'tx_simplepoll_domain_model_simplepoll');
        $renderObjName = '<tt_content.list.20.simplepoll_polllisting';
        $renderObjConf = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['tt_content.']['list.']['20.']['simplepoll_polllisting.'];

        $renderObjConf['persistence']['storagePid'] = 394; // This does not work!
        $renderObjConf['settings'] = $simplepollTs;
        $renderObjConf['settings']['simplepoll']['uid'] = $uid;


        return $cObj->cObjGetSingle($renderObjName, $renderObjConf);
    }
}
```

The viehelper is called like this:

```
{vh:LoadSimplepoll(uid: '{newsItem.simplepoll}')}
```

Now I am able to change the `uid` of the poll with this line:
`$renderObjConf['settings']['simplepoll']['uid'] = $uid;`

My problem is now, that it loads the poll, but not the answers. I tracked this down to the fact, that the plugin somehow does not know the `Record Storage Page` anymore. The line `$renderObjConf['persistence']['storagePid'] = 394;` does not help.

How can I tell the plugin the `Storage Pid`?

Or is there another/better way to load a plugin with changing data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shouldn't it be possible to modify `settings.simplepoll.uid` in typoscript?

because the extension **simplepoll** does not handle any stdWrap functionality to its typoscript settings.

Have a look into the code:
this special setting is used [here](https://github.com/pixelink/typo3-simplepoll/blob/83c607019f0d24a2be1e18253043120f72876d33/Classes/Controller/SimplePollController.php#L91):

```
$simplePoll = $this->simplePollRepository->findByUid($this->settings['simplepoll']['uid']);
```

no stdWrap, just plain usage.

compare it to `ext:news`:

before any settings is used it is processed. A dedicated join of typoscript settings with the settings in the plugin. And if necessary there is a stdWrap possible: [here](https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/2c8522ad508fa92ad39a5effe4301f7d872238a5/Classes/Controller/NewsController.php#L597)

```
    $this->originalSettings = $originalSettings;
    // Use stdWrap for given defined settings
    if (isset($originalSettings['useStdWrap']) && !empty($originalSettings['useStdWrap'])) {
        $typoScriptService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TypoScriptService::class);
        $typoScriptArray = $typoScriptService->convertPlainArrayToTypoScriptArray($originalSettings);
        $stdWrapProperties = GeneralUtility::trimExplode(',', $originalSettings['useStdWrap'], true);
        foreach ($stdWrapProperties as $key) {
            if (is_array($typoScriptArray[$key . '.'])) {
                $originalSettings[$key] = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->stdWrap(
                    $typoScriptArray[$key],
                    $typoScriptArray[$key . '.']
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see:
extbase does not support you with typoscript stdWrap functionality.
You (and every extension author) need to do it by hand. But that was so even before extbase.

In this way: as you can not configure your value you only can trick TYPO3 (and the plugin):
if you have a small number of uids you can have one variant for each uid

```
lib.loadSimplepoll123 < lib.loadSimplepoll
lib.loadSimplepoll123.settings.simplepoll.uid = 123

lib.loadSimplepoll234 < lib.loadSimplepoll
lib.loadSimplepoll234.settings.simplepoll.uid = 234

lib.loadSimplepoll345 < lib.loadSimplepoll
lib.loadSimplepoll345.settings.simplepoll.uid = 345

lib.loadSimplepoll456 < lib.loadSimplepoll
lib.loadSimplepoll456.settings.simplepoll.uid = 456
```

and call it like

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.loadSimplepoll{newsItem.simplepoll}" />
```

---

or you build a pull request implementing the stdWrap functionality and send it to the extension author.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your research and help! With a modified code of the above mentioned news extension, it is working. Conclusion for me: It is by default not possible to change settings when loading an extension via Typoscript.

Answer (score 0):

Why shouldn't it be possible to modify `settings.simplepoll.uid` in typoscript?
you just need the correct construction to modify it.

For a single value you can use `current`, but use it properly. It is a stdWrap function which needs to be evaluated.
If there is no `stdWrap` evaluation by default it might work with a `cObject` of type `TEXT`

```
settings.simplepoll.uid.cObject = TEXT
settings.simplepoll.uid.cObject.current = 1
```

or to indicate a `stdWrap` you need to use `stdWrap` literally:

```
settings.simplepoll.uid.stdWrap.current = 1
```

---

another variant of data transfer are named parameters. Just build an associative array as data parameter and access the values individual:

fluid:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.arraytest" data="{a:'abc',b:'xyz'}" >
    inside text
</f:cObject>
```

and the typoscript:

```
lib.arraytest = COA
lib.arraytest {
  10 = TEXT
  10.field = a
  10.wrap = /|/

  20 = TEXT
  20.field = b
  20.wrap = \|\
}
```

which results in an output of `/abc/\xyz\`. Be aware: the inner text of the `f:cobject` tag will be lost as the data parameter has priority about `inner children`.

Comment: I think I have tried both versions before (because they are mentioned in the linked forum post) and none is working:  `settings.simplepoll.uid.stdWrap.current = 1` will result in an array for $this->settings['simplepoll'] in the SimplePollController (`['uid']['stdWrap']['current']=1`) and `settings.simplepoll.uid.cObject = TEXT ...` generates an SQL error: `SELECT tx_simplepoll_domain_model_simplepoll.* FROM tx_simplepoll_domain_model_simplepoll WHERE tx_simplepoll_domain_model_simplepoll.uid = '1','TEXT' AND tx_simplepoll_domain_model_simplepoll.deleted=0 ...`

Comment: `settings.simplepoll.uid` probably doesn't have stdWrap. `cObject` also requires stdWrap.

Comment: in the forum post the last posting gives a solution which I doubt as `override` also based on `stdWrap`. Have you tried using `override.cobject.TEXT`? (on rendering time all `temp.*` objects do not exist any longer. The `<` operator copies the typoscript and so it is typoscript again, only with an `override`)

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ I have tried `settings.simplepoll.useStdWrap = uid  settings.simplepoll { uid.override.cObject < temp.pollUid }` without luck. `temp.pollUid` returns the uid of the poll. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I added another answer as for this case (ext:simplepoll) there seems to be no support for any flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I got the Viewhelpter to work:

Viewhelper:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\ViewHelpers;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;  

class LoadSimplepollViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function initializeArguments()
    {
        parent::initializeArguments();
        $this->registerArgument('simplepollUid', 'int', 'Uid of simplepoll', false);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        $configurationManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Configuration\\ConfigurationManager');
        $simplepollTs = $configurationManager->getConfiguration(
            \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_SETTINGS,
            'simplepoll',
            'Polllisting');

        $cObj = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer');
        $renderObjName = '<tt_content.list.20.simplepoll_polllisting';
        $renderObjConf = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['tt_content.']['list.']['20.']['simplepoll_polllisting.'];

        $renderObjConf['settings'] = $simplepollTs;
        $renderObjConf['settings']['simplepoll']['uid'] = (int)$this->arguments['simplepollUid'];

        return $cObj->cObjGetSingle($renderObjName, $renderObjConf);
    }
}
```

Call the viewhelper in the template (don't forget to register the namespace):

```
{vh:LoadSimplepoll(simplepollUid: '{newsItem.ipgSimplepoll}')}
```

That's it.